# Plesk 10 port 8443 connection timeout

Tags: centos5

I've installed plesk 10 on centOS and after installing to access the cp you need to go

https::8443

I'm not being able to, and would like to find out why

i can ssh to the server and i can, from the server telnet, to those ports.

from another machine i can ping it but when i try to telnet or go to that address i get connection timeout, happens with port 80 and 8443

from my netstat

```
netstat -nlp | grep 8443
tcp   0 0 :::8443   :::*  LISTEN      25205/sw-cp-serverd
```

How do i find out whats causing the problem? I also have a router but firewall is at the minimum and the server configured as DMZ, also tried to redirect 8443 to 8443 of the server.

Comment: Same situation for me.
iptables are clear: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Answer (score 1):

Could you give the result of "/sbin/iptables -L" ? I suspect iptables is blocking acccess to that port.